# Bash script to run over ssh cannot see remote file

Tags: bash, ssh

The script uses scp to upload a file. That works.

Now I want to log in with ssh, cd to the directory that holds the uploaded file, do an md5sum on the file. The script keeps telling me that md5sum cannot find $LOCAL_FILE. I tried escaping: \$LOCAL_FILE. Tried quoting the EOI: <<'EOI'. I'm partially understanding this, that no escaping means everything happens locally. echo `pwd` unescaped gives the local path. But why can I do "echo $MD5SUM > $LOCAL_FILE.md5sum", and it creates the file on the remote machine, yet "echo `md5sum $LOCAL_FILE` > md5sum2" does not work? And if it the local md5sum, how do I tell it to work on the remote?

---

```
scp "files/$LOCAL_FILE" "$i@$i.567.net":"$REMOTE_FILE_PATH"             

ssh -T "$i@$i.567.net" <<EOI                                                                       
touch I_just_logged_in                        
cd $REMOTE_DIRECTORY_PATH                     
echo `date` > I_just_changed_directories      
echo `whoami` >> I_just_changed_directories   
echo `pwd` >> I_just_changed_directories      
echo "$MD5SUM" >> I_just_changed_directories  
echo $MD5SUM > $LOCAL_FILE.md5sum             
echo `md5sum $LOCAL_FILE` > md5sum2           
EOI
```

Comment: there is something really odd about your script ... where does your EOI start? (your comment has it but your code snippet does not).  You should also give an example of what LOCAL_FILE looks like (is it a simple file name, are there spaces or special characters in the name)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about when `$LOCAL_FILE` is being interpreted.  In this case, since you've used double-quotes, it's being interpreted on the *sending* machine.  You need instead to quote the string in such a way that `$LOCAL_FILE` is in the command line on the *receiving* machine.  You also need to get your "here document" correct.  What you show just sends the output to `touch` to the ssh.

What you need will look something like

```
ssh -T address <'EOF'
cd $REMOTE_DIRECTORY_PATH
...
EOF
```

The quoting rules in `bash` are somewhat arcane.  You might want to read up on them in Mendel Cooper's [Advanced Guide to Bash Scripting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for the quick help. But it is even dumber than that. All I needed to do is: md5sum $LOCAL_FILE > md5sum2 (leaving off the echo in front) and it works.